# Where to find original windows vista cursors

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, download, themes, cursor

I reformatted my HDD and installed Windows 7 Ultimate. But i noticed the Windows Animated cursor theme from Windows Vista is gone. Any way to get it back, or an external download source?

I do have access to a Windows Vista installation CD, if they could be extracted from there.

Comment: Do you mean the [colorful 3D ones](http://www.geeksdesk.com/download-vista-sound-and-vista-cursors-for-windows-xp/)?

Comment: Close. This one isn't "3D", but it is colorful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Registry Editor to see a list of installed cursor themes at

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cursors\Schemes
```

(There is even a typo in the name of one of the schemes in Windows 7: `Windows Aero XL)`)

In any case, system cursors are stored at `%systemroot%\Cursors`, so if you have your Vista disk, you can extract them:

1. Get and install [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) if you don’t already have it
2. Use 7Zip to open the file `\Sources\Install.wim` from the DVD
3. Navigate to one of the folders (each number corresponds to a different edition of Windows—you can view `1.xml` to see which—but the cursors are available in all editions, so any of them will work)
4. Now navigate to `Windows\Cursors` and extract them somewhere
5. Examine the cursor files and keep the ones you want
6. Now you can select the files in the *Pointers* tab of the mouse control panel applet (`main.cpl`) and save it as *Windows Animated*

Comment: Nice! Well, it worked, and turns out that the one i was thinking of really was a custom theme installed by my laptop manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a "Windows Animated (system scheme)" in Vista and have extracted the necessary files :

[image]

Your can find the two zip-files here :

[Windows Animated.zip](http://depositfiles.com/files/b6j21ydae) - Extract the contained .reg file and double-click it.
[pointers.zip](http://depositfiles.com/files/ief7vaj49) - Contains Vista cursors missing in Windows 7. Extract them into `C:\Windows\Cursors`.

Now open Control Panel -> Mouse -> Pointers, and you should now have in the Scheme drop-down list a scheme named Windows Animated.

Comment: The name when you select a cursor theme is "Windows Animated". It comes with Windows Vista, and it is not "Windows Areo". This theme isn't in Windows 7.

Comment: Are you maybe referring to an animated wallpaper ?

Comment: Can you check if there is a cursor "set, theme, etc." in the Mouse Properties section of the Control Panel ?

Comment: Lol. It was just a theme from my manufacturer. I checked the disk files and the one i was looking for wasnt there

Comment: I don't think it is a manufacturer theme, as I finally found it in my vanilla Vista. I have rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=306790)'s the page with Vista cursors for download.

[Here](http://bronch.com/downloads/risherz/aero-cursors.zip)'s the direct link to the cursor zip.

Comment: Sorry. That's the "Windows Areo" theme from Windows Vista. I'm looking for the "Windows Animated" theme.

Comment: What do you mean Animated? That's the only animated cursor theme from Vista

Comment: @wolfo9999: The animated cursors in the zip file are the ones ending with ".ani". But these are also available in Windows 7.

Comment: Not the one that I want. This one *is* animated, the name is "Windows Animated", it has "(system scheme)" at the end, so I know it comes with windows vista, and it is not in windows 7

Comment: Vista had some more colorful cursors, just like it had more colorful tray icons.