# Windows Vista Cursors

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-vista, cursor

I am currently using Windows 10 Pro, but I want to have the Windows Vista cursor since I am more used to it.

Though, I don't know where to download them. Where can I get them?

Comment: Windows 10 has plentiful cursor styles. What specific Vista cursor do you need. Please edit your question to show a screenshot of what you need.

Comment: Check if this link contains what you want. http://www.rw-designer.com/tag/win-vista And there is another similar thread https://superuser.com/questions/464209/where-to-find-original-windows-vista-cursors, Synetech's help may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a zip of the vista themed cursors. Extract them to `C:\Windows\Cursors` and then browse to them when you are changing your pointer in control panel.

[aerocursors.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnjG9CbFmyAI4jCzj_PKKo7Jr2qIhAS6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted. I would like to improve. If anyone knows why this would be down-voted please inform me.